# word to say that something that is impressive

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

> He climbed the Everest, none the least.
>
> He climbed the Everest, none ____.
>
> He climbed the Everest, ____.

Forgot what the idiom was, but it's used to accentuate the fact that it's the most impressive thing, but I can't find the expression.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are remembering, but let’s start by correcting the grammar. “Everest” here is part of a proper noun, “Mount Everest.” The circumstances when it is correct to use an article with a proper noun are rare.

> He climbed Mount Everest

One phrase that you might be thinking of is “none the less.” That might be appropriate if there were some reason to find it particularly surprising.

> He lost his left hand in a car accident, but he climbed Mount Everest none the less

meaning

> Amazingly, he climbed Mount Everest despite having lost his left hand in a car accident.

Another phrase that you may be thinking of is “nothing less than” frequently used ironically.

> Yes, I agree that he is a decent climber. After all, he climbed nothing less than Mount Everest.

meaning

> It is absurd to say that someone who climbed Mount Everest is merely a decent climber.

Unless you can provide more information about what you intend to convey, it is impossible to be sure what phrase you are looking for.